# How and why do dummy variables work?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, substitution

When proving that $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(a+b-x) dx$$ the substitution $u = a+b-x$ is used, giving us the new integral $$\int_{a}^{b} f(u) du$$ After this, people will just swap $u$ with $x$ in order to satisfy the equality mentioned at the top of the post. Why is this allowed? Since $u$ is literally defined as being a different value than $x$, how can we make the two equal? When does this fail?

Comment: you need that $u: [a,b] \rightarrow R$ is a differentiable function with integrable derivative. Also, since you have $u(a) = b$ and $u(b) =a$, you get the integral $\int_{b}^{a} f(u) du = -\int_{a}^{b} f(u) du$.You should check the article on integration by substitution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution

Comment: Because the dummy variable $x$ used in the intergral means : for every value of the variable ($x$) in the inetrval $[a,b]$. Thus, when you change the variable name, nothing change : it is again for every...

Comment: Take a look at this article on [free variables and bound variables.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) In the context of your question, the "dummy variable" is just a special kind of bound variable.

Comment: Can you see why $\sum_{i = 1}^{10} i^2$ is the same as $\sum_{n = 1}^{10}n^2$? The integration case is completely analoguous.

Comment: But are there any cases that fail? It just doesn’t make sense since after you substitute, you’re integrating over a new coordinate system with values of $u$ corresponding with values of $x$ being modified in some way (like $u=x^2$ means that every number on the $u,f(u)$ plane is just that number square on the $x,y$ plane. So the two variables can’t really be equal right?

Comment: $f(u)du$ and $f(x)dx$ are the same thing. If I define $f(x)=x^2$ then say $f(t)=t^2$ we don't question anything here do we?

Answer (score 2):

The value of the integral $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ depends only on the function $f$ and on the constants $a,b$; if you want, it's the area under $f$ between $a$ and $b$. It doesn't depend on any specific value of $x$; in fact we're using $x$ as a placeholder variable taking (in a sense) all the values between $a$ and $b$.

When you make the substitution for $u$, you make it at each specific value of $x$, and at a specific value, $u$ and $x$ are different, as you noted. But you end up with the integral $\int_a^b f(u)du$, which again just means we're taking the area under $f$ between $a$ and $b$. We got there using a different variable, but the value of the integral itself doesn't care which variable is used. That's what a dummy variable is.

Answer (score 0):

When substituting $u=a+b-x$, $du=-dx$, $x=a\rightarrow u=b,x=b\rightarrow u=a$
$$\int_a^bf\left(x\right)dx=\int_a^b -f\left(u\right)du$$
Because of $\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$,
$$\int_a^b -f\left(u\right)du=\int_a^bf\left(u\right)du$$

Comment: I stated that at the end without providing all the steps, but for the last integral, why can you just replace $u$ with $x$?

Comment: Actually, it is not replacing, there are some steps between them so as to get this result. Symmetric is the reason.

Comment: What would those steps be, and how are they symmetric since $u$ and $x$ differ by $a$ and $b$?

Comment: My answer is the step, ok?

Comment: Consider the graph $f\left(x\right)$, you'll find that the region from $x=a$ to $x=b$ in the graph $f\left(x\right)$ and $f\left(a+b-x\right)$ has the same because of reflection.